# How to validate E-Mail Address Format

Tags: vb.net

I found following code from this link.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01escwtf(v=vs.80).aspx

```
Function IsValidEmail(strIn As String) As Boolean
' Return true if strIn is in valid e-mail format.
Return Regex.IsMatch(strIn, "^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$")
End Function
```

I dont know how to use above code.
I mean how to call above code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/201323/1070452

Comment: To use it, you probably have to import System.Text.RegularExpressions, and then just call it like: If IsValidEmail("me@domain.com") Then...

Comment: The code you posted is a function that takes a `String` as input and returns a `Boolean` to indicate if the format is valid for an e-mail address.

Comment: Update title of the question - it is misleading for people who answers only based on title :)

Comment: The same. `If IsValidEmail("somebody@somewhere.com") Then `valid format`.

Comment: The page you referring to is obsolete and provide a link to newer version with code examples: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01escwtf(v=vs.110).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01escwtf(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use it as below

```
If IsValidEmail("inputemail@domain.com") Then
        'valid email
Else
       'invalid email
End If
```